# Average length of comments on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, comments, data-analysis

What is the **average comment length** on Stack Overflow?

I'm working on my thesis about *short message topic detection* (on Twitter, to be more specific), and I would like to know that for research purposes.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: *155* characters at this point of time.

Comment: The [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) rather than the average might be more useful. The distribution is more like to follow a power law than a normal distribution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

14**6** characters.

To get the precise value, one should use floating-point arithmetic. The query is:

```sql
SELECT AVG(CAST(LEN(Text) AS FLOAT)) FROM Comments
```

This gives 145.98293005330171, or very close to 146. Beware of integer division when your result is not an integer!

Interesting features in the graph of the distribution include:

- Very few comments less than 15 chars (the UI now prevents such short comments)
- An upturn for the longest comments, at or just below the 600-char maximum
- A smaller upturn around 300 (I assume there used to be a 300-char limit, now removed)

Comment: That's exactly the very same query I ran when @Bart pointed me to http://data.stackexchange.com ;-)

Answer (score 8):

As of now, [145](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97677).

[The distribution is probably more useful](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97683), though.

Comment: See also the graph of the distribution: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97683#graph

Answer (score 4):

145 characters.

Query: [Average Comment Length](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97690/average-comment-length)

Answer (score 3):

[Here it is](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97676/average-comment-length)

```sql
SELECT SUM(CAST(LEN(Text) as bigint))/COUNT(*) FROM Comments;
```